# No puedo acceder a una base de datos con BD Browser for SQLite - Windows 10

Tags: base-de-datos, sqlite, wsl

mi problema es en un curso donde descargue una repo con una base de datos de prueba e instale el BD Browser for SQlite en windows 10 (todo esto dentro de un ambiente WSL), el problema esta en que al cargar el archivo el programa no quiere abrirme la base de datos, indicando que esta se encuentra bloqueada,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Dónde puede estar el problema?,

De antemano, muchas gracias!!

Comment: El archivo ya esta abierto? es de solo lectura?

Comment: si estas usando wsl, revisa los permisos del archivo, tiene que estar lectura y escritura